# optimize/tune setting to spark job, where the job uses groupbyKey and reduceGroups

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I am trying to see if there are any settings like executor memory, cores, shuffle partition or anything we can think of that might speed up a job which includes `union`,`GroupByKey`, and `reduceGroups` operations

I understand these intense operations to perform and its currently taking 5 hours to finish this.

example:

```
.union(transitive)
  .union(family)
  .groupByKey(_.key)
  .reduceGroups((left, right) =>
```

spark submit

```
"Step5_Spark_Command": "command-runner.jar,spark-submit,--class,com.ms.eng.link.modules.linkmod.Links,--name,\\\"Links\\\",--master,yarn,--deploy-mode,client,--executor-memory,32G,--executor-cores,4,--conf,spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2020,/home/hadoop/linking.jar,jobId=#{myJobId},environment=prod",
```

The function

```
val family =
      generateFamilyLinks(references, superNodes.filter(_.linkType == FAMILY))
        .checkpoint(eager = true)
    direct
      .union(reciprocal)
      .union(transitive)
      .union(family)
      .groupByKey(_.key)
      .reduceGroups((left, right) =>
        left.copy(
          contributingReferences = left.contributingReferences ++ right.contributingReferences,
          linkTypes = left.linkTypes ++ right.linkTypes,
          contexts = left.contexts ++ right.contexts
        )
      )
      .map(group =>
        group._2.copy(
          contributingReferences = ArrayUtil.dedup(group._2.contributingReferences, _.key)
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By looking into your spark-submit command, I can see you're running Spark on YARN. But may I ask why on client mode? Actually in your case your driver and executors are both being created in local only and not leveraging the resources of your cluster fully. So, use --deploy-mode cluster instead.

For hardware provisioning, use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236440/pyspark-adding-executors-makes-app-slower/48280978#48280978).

Hope, this helps in scaling your app.

Comment: do you think switching to cluster mode will enhance the performance? Can you expand on what you mean by drivers and executors being created locally?