# convert groupByKey to reduceBykey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to convert the following `groupByKey` to a `reduceByKey`.

```scala
block.groupByKey(_.key)
      .reduceGroups((left, right) =>
        left.copy(
          contributingReferences = left.contributingReferences ++ right.contributingReferences,
          linkTypes = left.linkTypes ++ right.linkTypes,
          contexts = left.contexts ++ right.contexts
        )
      )
      .map(group =>
        group._2.copy(
          contributingReferences = ArrayUtil.dedup(group._2.contributingReferences, _.key)
        )
      )
```

How do I accomplish this going past the scala sugar syntax like the `(_+_)`?

This is an example I have found

```
val words = Array("one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three")
val wordPairsRDD = sc.parallelize(words).map(word => (word, 1))

val wordCountsWithReduce = wordPairsRDD
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .collect()

val wordCountsWithGroup = wordPairsRDD
  .groupByKey()
  .map(t => (t._1, t._2.sum))
  .collect()
```

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. Is this an attempt to optimize [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48392065/6910411)?

Comment: yea sir, that is it

Comment: __TL;DR__ It won't help you, and in fact there is nothing to rewrite here. If no one answers this, I'll provide a more elaborate answer later. In a meantime would you mind replacing image of code with the code itself, and add encoder / schema definition and imports / type definitions (for `CountMap` and the rest)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i thought reducyByKeys can be avoided to better performance: https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html